# Writing to specific row on a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, np

I have an array that indicates the row numbers I would like to mark.

```
example_array = [3, 101, 505, 1020, 3500]
```

Inside a dataframe, I have a column name called df["indicator"] and would to mark the specific rows of that column as noted in the example_array with a "PROBLEM" string. Basically, on the 3rd row of df["indicator"], 101th row, and so on I would like to mark it as a PROBLEM.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `loc` with assignment; Pass the `example_array` as the row index and `indicator` as column index:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"indicator": [""]*5})
>>> df
  indicator
0          
1          
2          
3          
4          

>>> example_array = [0,3]
>>> df.loc[example_array, "indicator"] = "problem"

>>> df
  indicator
0   problem
1          
2          
3   problem
4
```

Comment: This is how I would do it. Alternatively you could use `iloc` for if the index is not numeric: `df.iloc[example_array, df.columns == "indicator"] = "problem"`